# Json parse not convert to object

Tags: javascript, json, object

My `API` return user object and format is like that=>

```
{'id': '1', 'username': 'admin', 'image': 'https://user/testing.png', 'phno': '123'}
```

First I do JSON.stringify and I check the type of this line is a string.

So I use JSON.parse to get an object but its still string and can't get it likes `user.id` is undefined.

How can I get like `user.id`, `user.username`,...?

```
console.log(user);
console.log(user.user);

var test = JSON.stringify(user.user);
console.log(typeof(test));

var test1 = JSON.parse(test);
console.log(test1.id);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem might be that your API is returning JSON data with single quotation marks, and JavaScript is not able to parse it correctly. Check which JSON serializer you're using on server side. It should be like: `{"id": "1", "username": "admin", "image": "https://user/testing.png", "phno": "123"}`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for your data:

```js
var data = '{"id": "1", "username": "admin", "image": "https://user/testing.png", "phno": "123"}';
var user = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(user.id);
```

Comment: A notice - JSON format is supposed to have `"` in it, not single quotes

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not getting exact user json. Issue may be backend.

```js
const obj = `{"user":"{\\"id\\": \\"1\\", \\"username\\": \\"admin\\", \\"image\\": \\"https://user/testing.png\\", \\"phno\\": \\"123\\"}"}`
console.log(obj)
// First get value of user.
let user = JSON.parse(obj).user
console.log(typeof user) //string
// parse again, since user is string
user = JSON.parse(user)
console.log(user.username)
console.log(user.id)
```